# How to hover on text to have a video appear and play?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I want to hover on text and have a video appear and play when the user hovers and when you are not hovering, the video would disappear.

I found the following on [codepen](https://codepen.io/aemabit/pen/KKKxZxb) which does work for both images and video when hovering on specific text, but when I copy the HTML code to list another video since I don't want this for images the next video won't play. It will only play the first video listed. Please help!

```js
function vidPlay() {  
  $("#video1").get(0).play();  
};
function vidPause() {
    $("#video1").get(0).pause();
};
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#textToggler").click(function(){
    $(".toggleText").toggle();
  });
});
function toggleImage() {
  $(".hiddenclickimg").toggle();
};
```

```css
.hiddenimg {
  display: none;
}

.hiddentxt {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #F00;
  z-index:99;
}

.hiddentxt a {
  color: #F00;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 99;
}

.hiddenclick {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #F00;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hiddenclick a {
  color: #F00;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hiddenclick a:visited {
  color: #F00;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hiddentxt:hover ~ .hiddenimg {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
    z-index: 2
}

.hiddenclickimg {
  display: none;

}
```

```html
<head>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>
    Hover to see a <span class="hiddentxt"><a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8a/Banana-Single.jpg">banana</a></span><span class="hiddenimg"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8a/Banana-Single.jpg" width="250" /></span>.
  </p>
  <p>
    Let's see if it works with <span class="hiddentxt" onmouseover="vidPlay()" onmouseout="vidPause()"><a href="https://mtc.cdn.vine.co/r/videos/ECBC329ACC1050514912117440512_1c6599f182f.4.6.16444000809832514200.mp4">videos</a></span>. (The video should play when it's displayed, but sometimes it takes a while to load.)
    <span class="hiddenimg"><video id="video1" loop>
      <source src="https://mtc.cdn.vine.co/r/videos/ECBC329ACC1050514912117440512_1c6599f182f.4.6.16444000809832514200.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video></span>
  </P>
  <p> Click <span class = "hiddenclick" onclick = "toggleImage()">here</span> to show image.<br>
  <span class="hiddenclickimg"><img src = "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/22/74/8c/22748c9b9cc2c039aed206cab0247404.gif"/></span>
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: That's because ID should be **unique**! Multiple elements? **Use classes instead**.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I am very new to coding and such and I found that example, which I guess is bad. How do I use classes instead? Can you help me write new code for text hover to display/play a video? Thank you!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I don't see any duplicated IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Use classes instead of ID. IDs (as the name suggests) should be **unique**.
Here's an example how to hover to play/pause multiple videos - without the unnecessary jQuery:

```js
const ELS_aVid = document.querySelectorAll(".hoverVid");

const toggleVideo = (ev) => {
  const EL = ev.currentTarget;
  const EL_video = EL.querySelector("video");
  const isPlay = ev.type === "mouseenter";
  EL_video[isPlay ? "play" : "pause"]();
};

ELS_aVid.forEach(EL => {
  ["mouseenter", "mouseleave"]
    .forEach(evt => EL.addEventListener(evt, toggleVideo))
});
```

```css
.hoverVid  {
  position: relative;
}

.hoverVid video {
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

  /* "hidden" and prepared animation state*/
  transition: 0.5s;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateY(20px);
}

.hoverVid:hover video {
  /* on hover, animate into view */
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

```html
<a class="hoverVid" href="https://mtc.cdn.vine.co/r/videos/ECBC329ACC1050514912117440512_1c6599f182f.4.6.16444000809832514200.mp4">
  Hover to watch video
  <video loop src="https://mtc.cdn.vine.co/r/videos/ECBC329ACC1050514912117440512_1c6599f182f.4.6.16444000809832514200.mp4"></video>
</a>

<br>
or if you feel like 

<a class="hoverVid" href="https://mtc.cdn.vine.co/r/videos/ECBC329ACC1050514912117440512_1c6599f182f.4.6.16444000809832514200.mp4">
  watch the same video again LOL
  <video loop src="https://mtc.cdn.vine.co/r/videos/ECBC329ACC1050514912117440512_1c6599f182f.4.6.16444000809832514200.mp4"></video>
</a>
```

Search for any JavaScript Method you don't understand (like i.e: `querySelectorAll` or `forEach`) on [the MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

Comment: Thank you so much for this code! I greatly appreciate it. I will look into the classes and everything.